# MODIS LDOPE mask_sds Error

Tags: modis

I am using the LDOPE mask_sds tool to mask a MODIS image based on the quality flags for MOD13A3 NDVI.  The full command that I am using is:

```
mask_sds -of=mask.hdf -fill=-3000 -sds='1km monthly NDVI' -mask="MOD13A3.A2000336.h25v02.005.2007112105435.hdf,'1km monthly VI Quality',0-1==00,AND,*,*,11-13==001" -meta MOD13A3.A2000336.h25v02.005.2007112105435.hdf
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Cannot find the SDS '1km monthly VI Quality' 
Ignoring input masking option MOD13A3.A2000336.h25v02.005.2007112105435.hdf,'1km monthly VI Quality',0-1==00,AND
Cannot open the input HDF file *
Cannot open the HDF file *
Ignoring input masking option *,*,11-13==001
usage: 
    mask_sds -help [filename] 

    mask_sds -of=<output filename> -sds=<SDSname1>[,<SDSname2>[,...]]> 
    [-fill=<mask fill value>] -mask=<mask1>[,AND|OR,<mask2>[,...]] [-meta]
    filename 
       where maskn=< filename>,<SDSname>,<bit_numbers operator bit_values>
```

It looks like it can not find the SDS (science data set) for the quality flag.  I have tried several variations of '1km monthly VI Quality', including without quotes.  This [website](http://landweb.nascom.nasa.gov/cgi-bin/QA_WWW/sds.cgi) lists SDS's for each MODIS product (I am using MOD13A3).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were two issues with my mask_sds command call:

1. You need to use double quotes for the first SDS, and no quotes for the second SDS (originally, I had used single quotes for each).
2. 1km should be 1 km (with a space between *1* and *km*

   mask_sds -of=mask.hdf -fill=-3000 **-sds="1 km monthly NDVI"** -mask="MOD13A3.A2000336.h25v02.005.2007112105435.hdf,**1 km monthly VI Quality**,0-1==00,AND,*,*,11-13==001" -meta MOD13A3.A2000336.h25v02.005.2007112105435.hdf

Unfortunately there is very little documentation on the LDOPE tool (other than the user manual, which didn't help much with my problem).  I had to resort to trial and error until (after I invested way too much time) I found the right syntax.